# Сложить данные из объектов с одинаковым значением

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть вот такой массив:

```
[{
        id: 100,
        chance: 10
    },
    {
        id: 100,
        chance: 30
    },
    {
        id: 200,
        chance: 10
    },
    {
        id: 300,
        chance: 5
    },
    {
        id: 200,
        chance: 30
    },
    {
        id: 100,
        chance: 15
    }
]
```

Как сделать цикл, чтобы возвращал он подобное:

```
id:100 chance: 55 (10+30+15 выводить не надо)
id:200 chance: 40 (10+30 выводить не надо)
id:300 chance: 5
```

Нужно чтобы цикл складывал `chance` у объектов с одинаковым `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Группировка по `id` с помощью объекта и вывод на экран `id` + `chance`:

```js
var data = [{ id: 100, chance: 10 }, { id: 100, chance: 30 }, { id: 200, chance: 10 },
            { id: 300, chance: 5 }, { id: 200, chance: 30 }, { id: 100, chance: 15 }];
var result = {};
for (var element of data)
{
  if (result[element.id] == undefined)
    result[element.id] = 0;
  result[element.id] += element.chance;
} 
for (var id in result)
  console.log("id: " + id + ", chance: " + result[id]);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691308/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0 посмотришь?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с reduce, впрочем, принципиально он ничем не отличается от ответа Regent

```js
let data = [{
        id: 100,
        chance: 10
    },
    {
        id: 100,
        chance: 30
    },
    {
        id: 200,
        chance: 10
    },
    {
        id: 300,
        chance: 5
    },
    {
        id: 200,
        chance: 30
    },
    {
        id: 100,
        chance: 15
    }
];
let result = data.reduce((prev, item) => {
 if (item.id in prev) {
  prev[item.id] += item.chance
 } else {
  prev[item.id] = item.chance;
 }
 return prev;
}, {})
Object.keys(result).forEach(id => {
 console.log(`id:${id}, chance:${result[id]}`);
})
```