# Обновление переменной из сокета

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть код который складывает данные из массивов

```
var data = [{ id: 100, chance: 10 }, { id: 100, chance: 30 }, { id: 200, chance: 10 },
            { id: 300, chance: 5 }, { id: 200, chance: 30 }, { id: 100, chance: 15 }];
var result = {};
for (var element of data)
{
  if (result[element.id] == undefined)
    result[element.id] = 0;
  result[element.id] += element.chance;
} 
for (var id in result)
  console.log("id: " + id + ", chance: " + result[id]);
```

Этот код выполняется только один раз после загрузки страницы - пусть это будет `socket.on('load_data',...)`
Но на страницу так же постоянно приходит и другой сокет запрос `socket.on('bet_data',...)`
Так вот..

Вместе с `bet_data` приходит data в таком виде `data = { id: 400, chance: 10 }`.

События получается выглядят вот так:

```
socket.on('load_data', function(data) {
    var data = [{ id: 100, chance: 10 }, { id: 100, chance: 30 }, { id: 200, chance: 10 },
                { id: 300, chance: 5 }, { id: 200, chance: 30 }, { id: 100, chance: 15 }];
    var result = {};
    for (var element of data)
    {
      if (result[element.id] == undefined)
        result[element.id] = 0;
      result[element.id] += element.chance;
    } 
    for (var id in result)
      console.log("id: " + id + ", chance: " + result[id]);
});

socket.on('bet_data', function(data) {
    var data = { id: 400, chance: 10 };
    // тут нужно сделать сделать обновление переменной result, и (занести/добавить к существующему) новый результат.
});
```

Надеюсь объяснил понятно..

Comment: делай переменную result - глобальной

Comment: при выполнении кода с таким объектом как в `bet_data` - ошибка data[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: ну так очевидно потому, что у тебя data в load_data - массив, а в bet_data единственный объект

Comment: Ну я понимаю, что мне с этим делать?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант - сделать переменную `result` глобальной и вынести код добавления в `result` в функцию:

```js
var result = {};

function addToResult(id, chance)
{
  if (result[id] == undefined)
    result[id] = 0;
  result[id] += chance;
}

//socket.on('load_data'
setTimeout(function() {
  var data = [{ id: 100, chance: 10 }, { id: 100, chance: 30 }, { id: 200, chance: 10 },
              { id: 300, chance: 5 }, { id: 200, chance: 30 }, { id: 100, chance: 15 }];
  for (var element of data)
    addToResult(element.id, element.chance);
}, 10);

//socket.on('bet_data'
setTimeout(function() {
  var data = { id: 400, chance: 10 };
  addToResult(data.id, data.chance);
  //проверка результата
  for (var id in result)
    console.log("id: " + id + ", chance: " + result[id]);
}, 100);
```